# Best way to port C++ code that uses a bidirectional popen() to POSIX

Tags: c++, c, posix

I'm trying to get some C++ code running on Linux that a colleague wrote for OS X. It's mostly portable, but there's one part I don't know how to handle. He uses `popen(CMD, "r+")` to open a bidirectional pipe and communicates with the process through `fget` and `fprint`.

On Linux the type `r+` is not available as pipes can only be unidirectional. I guess usually the way would be to handle bidirectional communication through a socket but the called `CMD` is an interactive program over which we have only limited control.

After some searching I found some snippets for a `popen2` implementation in C. It works kinda but it would be much easier if there would be a real "C++" way to do it using streams instead of low-level functions like `write` and `read`. Also I have some problems where a lot of communication gets missing.

Anyway, my question is: What is the best way to port code that uses bidirectional `popen()` to POSIX (or at least OS X + Linux)?

Comment: Maybe `<ext/stdio_filebuf.h>` would interest you? Its a `GCC` file-buffer that wraps either a `FILE*` or a *file descriptor* so you can turn it into a `std::iostream`.

Comment: The usual way is to set up the process manually: Create two set of pipes, one for stdin, one for stdout, `fork`, `dup2` the right ends to the right fd's, and `execv` the desired process. (Remember to `exit` if `execv` fails.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Galik and Philip. I'm wondering if there's a library (maybe part of Boost or similar) that handles this? As I'm not really familiar with these low-level aspects.

Comment: Sure, there's [Boost.Process](http://www.highscore.de/boost/process/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[socketpair(2)](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman2/socketpair.2.html) creates a pair of sockets that are endpoints of a bidirectional pipe. This will directly replace `popen()`. I do not see why `CMD` being or not being an interactive program has anything to do with it.

It is possible that the program might need to have an actual terminal device (unlikely, since `popen`() doesn't really emulate one). If so, the [pty(7)](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman7/pty.7.html) man page provides additional documentation for creating a bi-directional pipe that drives a pseudo-tty device.

Comment: "I do not see why CMD being or not being an interactive program has anything to do with it" - I believe that OP means that the program is controlled via stdin/stdout, and did not realise that a socket can be connected to stdin/stdout.

Comment: socketpair does not allow running a program. Therefore, it is not a replacement for popen.